# mapbox geocoding api used in Unity bug on iOS

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-ios

we're using this api to fetch the city and country in a unity game: https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/

On android it works without any issues, for iOS it doesn't give the location on certain devices. In the logs we see that the location it takes is on the other side of the world.
Is there anything different to be done on Xcode or in a Unity build for iOS regarding this api?

Comment: Try asking a more specific question, or including more information, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

In general there should not be a difference, as you are talking to the Mapbox API, which does not care where the request originated from.

Can you please catch the exact HTTP GET request that you are sending to https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/ ?